# How to do a SOAP api callout from apex

Tags: apex, api, soap-api

```
    //Generated by wsdl2apex

public class RSSInterface {
    public class TestContractResponse_element {
        public String TestContractResult;
        private String[] TestContractResult_type_info = new String[]{'TestContractResult','https://12.13.89.100:8642/.RSS.InterfaceService.WCF.Salesforce',null,'0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'https://12.13.89.100:8642/.RSS.InterfaceService.WCF.Salesforce','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'TestContractResult'};
    }
    public class TestContract_element {
        public String CustomerNumber;
        public String UserInfo;
        private String[] CustomerNumber_type_info = new String[]{'CustomerNumber','https://12.13.89.100:8642/.RSS.InterfaceService.WCF.Salesforce',null,'0','1','true'};
        private String[] UserInfo_type_info = new String[]{'UserInfo','https://test/RSS.InterfaceService.WCF.Salesforce',null,'0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'https://test/RSS.InterfaceService.WCF.Salesforce','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'CustomerNumber','UserInfo'};
    }
    public class CustomBinding_IWCFSalesforce {
        public String endpoint_x = 'https://test/RSS.InterfaceService.WCF.Salesforce';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/', 'SchemasM', 'https://test/RSS.InterfaceService.WCF.Salesforce', 'RSSInterface'};
        public String TestContract(String CustomerNumber,String UserInfo) {
            RSSInterface.TestContract_element request_x = new RSSInterface.TestContract_element();
            request_x.CustomerNumber = CustomerNumber;
            request_x.UserInfo = UserInfo;
            RSSInterface.TestContractResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, RSSInterface.TestContractResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, RSSInterface.TestContractResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'https://test/RSS.InterfaceService.WCF.Salesforce/IWCFSalesforce/TestContract',
              'https://test/RSS.InterfaceService.WCF.Salesforce',
              'TestContract',
              'https://test/RSS.InterfaceService.WCF.Salesforce',
              'TestContractResponse',
              'RSSInterface.TestContractResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.TestContractResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my understanding of the trailheads if i wanted to say, execute the TestContract_element anonymously i would simply

```
GTRSSInterface.TestContract_element calltest = new IGTRSSInterface.TestContract_element();{
    string testf = 'hello';
    string testy = 'world';
        }
```

And salesforce SHOULD make an attempt at doing a callout to my RSS server, the RSS server in turn SHOULD have packets hit it...as long as it's been added in Remote Site Settings...right?

Because I'm looking for any packet contact from SFDC to my RSS server and i'm not seeing anything, i don't care if it executes the method or not i just want packets from salesforce to hit my RSS server via these SOAP callouts and right now thats not happening.....there's zero traffic from around the time i execute the code hitting my RSS server...

Can someone just help me with a quick execute anonymous command that will just shoot ANYTHING over to the RSS server via this WSDL. It doesn't actually have to do anything i just need to see some traffic on my network end.

Answer (score 0):

`RssInterface` has an inner class `CustomBinding_IWCFSalesforce` which has `TestContract` method which does the callout.  You have to create an instance of `RssInterface.CustomBinding_IWCFSalesforce` which will allow you to do callout.

So your code to do callout will be

```
String responseString = new RSSInterface.CustomBinding_IWCFSalesforce().TestContract('28663' ,'pranay.com');
```